# Выборка данных с двух разных таблиц SQL

Tags: php, sql

В общем, ломаю уже третий день голову над очередным вопросом: есть 2 таблицы, обе имеют разные столбцы и названия и типы данных, цель - вытащить записи с обоих таблиц в один цикл, допустим есть такие таблицы:

```
table_one (в ней столбцы: userid, date, summ, type)
table_us (в ней столбцы: user, price, date, type_is)
```

И мне поставили цель - вывести записи с этих таблиц в 1 цикл, я сразу подумал через `UNION`, но он выводит только при условии, что столбцы и их типы данных одинаковы, а тут, как видите, разные, собственно, очень прошу, кто знает можете привести пример запроса и цикла вывода на PHP, буду очень благодарен (новичок).

В поле userid и user - id пользователя, то есть наша задача вывести записи с двух таблиц по id пользователя.

Comment: Прочитайте про `JOIN`.

Comment: @u_mulder а можете привести пример? У меня уже голова отвалится скоро, сайтов 30 перечитал с яндекса уже, был бы очень благодарен

Comment: https://anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-join/

Comment: Приведите пример данных (2-3 записи) каждой таблицы, и требуемый результат на таких данных.

Comment: @Akina В поле userid и user - id пользователя, то есть наша задача вывести записи с двух таблиц по id пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Ну очень схематично:

```
$result = query(" SELECT userid, date, summ, type, NULL user, NULL price, NULL date2, NULL type_is 
                  FROM table1
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, user, price, date, type_is
                  FROM table2 ");

for each $record in $result {
    if $record("userid") { 
        echo "from table1", $record("userid"), $record("date"), $record("summ"), $record("type");
    } else {
        echo "from table2", $record("user"), $record("price"), $record("date2"), $record("type_is");
    }
}
```

При всём идиотизме - должно работать.

Comment: Мне все-таки кажется что `userid` и `user` должны хранить связь таблиц друг с другом.

Comment: @u_mulder Да мы вообще не в курсе, есть ли там хоть какая связь. Может, эти таблицы вообще никак не связаны логически.

Comment: @Akina связь есть в столбце user и userid ид юзера записи которого нужно вывести, тоесть задача вывести записи юзера с обоех таблиц. 
Юзер пишется в виде id (не логина)